# Starting an activity in a seperate "window"

Tags: android

I've been struggling with this for quite some time now. 
Basically I have an application which will be used to start pendingIntent alarms. The user will set a specific time for the alarm which eventually fires off and as a result starts a new activity.

My problem here is that this new started activity by the pending intent opens up in the same "window" as the mainActivity(where the user set up the alarms etc). 
I would like to get this new activity as a new separate window, completely disconnected from the mainActivity.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putLong("AlarmNoteID", note.getId());
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), (int) note.getId(), myIntent, 0);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

and the AlarmReceiver class contains the following

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        DBHelper_general DBInstance = DBHelper_general.getsInstance(context);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Long ID = bundle.getLong("AlarmNoteID");

        if (DBInstance.getNote(ID) != null) {
            Intent intentNewAct = new Intent();
            intentNewAct.putExtra("AlarmNoteID", ID);

            intentNewAct.setClassName("com.example.myPackage", "com.example.myPackage.AlarmActivatedActivity");
            intentNewAct.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intentNewAct);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I seem to have gotten this to work now.
The missing flag: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT was needed for the Intent.